# Unreal Engine 4 minimum distance of camera from object

Tags: camera, unreal-engine4

I placed a standard Camera in front of a moving Actor. When I set the current view to this camera I noticed a strange behaviour: If the actor get really close to another object on the scenario (a default cube) it disappear from the view. It looks like the camera is getting into the cube. I'm pretty sure the camera is not colliding with the cube because the actor has a couple of bumpers that prevent the side where the camera is placed to collide with other objects and the whole camera mesh is placed fully 'inside' the actor. The problem maybe is related with the size of the actor that's about 40cm x 30cm x 10cm. The observed cube is 1mt x 1mt x 1mt, the minimum distance of camera from cube is around 3 cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're experiencing an issue with an object passing your camera's "clipping plane." In the 3D world, this is simply just draw distance minimum and maximum values. For more information on what you are experiencing, check out this brilliant explanation by Autodesk: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Rendering/files/GUID-D69C23DA-ECFB-4D95-82F5-81118ED41C95-htm.html

Now, let's fix the issue! In Unreal Engine, it's super easy. Go into your Project Settings/General Settings. There is a value called `Near Clip Plane`, which simply changes the minimum clipping value for Camera components. I would bet making this value smaller will fix your issue! For a visual representation, check out this tutorial by Kyle Dail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO79qxNnOfU

Comment: I did and it worked but had to set this parameter to 0.01 that sounds pretty strange keeping into account that the camera cannot hit the cube for geometric reasons. I think that the focal point of the camera is set far beyond its mesh (talking in cm scale of course).